# Beat Satan with The Lost, unlocked achievement but not "The Mind". Is it bugged?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I beat Satan with The Lost but didn't get the item, only the achievement. Why did this happen? I am wondering if I have to actually win the run (beat The Lamb) in order to get the item. Did something bug out or is it part of the game. Also, it was not a seeded run. Thanks!

Comment: As far as i know, it is not bugged, i unlocked it several weeks ago. Did you cheat the lost or did you unlock it "legal"?

Comment: @YUNOWORK it's funny to see your nickname when talking about a bug

Comment: @pinckerman Well, actually, this was my name for stackoverflow ... programming and stuff. My nickname was my typical reaction after 2 hours coding without achieving anything. But i guess my name fits into everything technical.^^

Comment: @YUNOWORK I'm a programmer too, I know what you mean :)

Answer (score 5):

If what you're saying is that you received the achievement "The Mind", but the corresponding item didn't appear in the item chart or in game, that's how it's supposed to be.

Beating a boss only unlocks the item for the future, meaning that after beating the boss, you can find the item in subsequent runs.

Comment: Just like all other unlocked items